# Creating substrings using colons as my indexes

Tags: java, for-loop, methods, substring

I am attempting to create a method that accepts a string in the form of:
 "something a : something b : something c"

I need to ignore the colons, and store the various somethings as variables (private).

I have my getters and setters, as well as my toString. I am, however, having issue with creating my for loop and proper substrings there in to create my three separate variables (something a, something b, something c).  I am also having issue with how the method is going to receive inputs from the command line.

Here is my code so far

```
public void createList(String a) {
    //creates an arrayList to store the variables
    int index = 0;
    int i = a.indexOf(':'); //uses the indexOf(':') as the start/end of the substring
    for(int j = 0, j < a.length(); j++){
        xxxx = a.substring(0 , i - 1); //something a
        yyyy = a.substring(i + 1, i - 1); //something b
        zzzz = a.substring(i + 1, a.length() - 1); // something c
}
```

I have a separate main method that accepts inputs from the command line (.txt files).

Comment: use `a.split(" : ")`

Answer (score 0):

As aioobe said, `a.split(" : ")` will give you a `String[]` whose elements are going to be each piece of the input separated by `:`.

From there, your code would simplify to:

```
String[] array = a.split(" : ");
xxx = array[0];
yyy = array[1];
zzz = array[2];
```